# Repair a forced fsck-ed LUKS volume

Tags: data-recovery, fsck, luks, disk-encryption, vulnerabilities

In a moment of distraction, I'v managed to run:
`# fsck -Ty /dev/sda1`, where **/dev/sda1*** was a **LUKS encypted volume**.

I don't have a recent backup, so I can't restore. And the backup I have is for the data inside the partition, not for the encrypted volume itself.  But I do know the password.

The data I'v lost is very important. Is there any way I can restore/recover?

If I try to open it, `# cryptsetup open /dev/sda1 enc_part`, I'm getting the error ***Device /dev/sda1 is not a valid LUKS device***. No surprise.

The partition was encrypted with the vulnerable **cryptsetup 2.1.0-5+deb10u2**, using the following options:  `# cryptsetup luksFormat -c anubis-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h whirlpool --keyslot-cipher=anubis-xts-plain64 --keyslot-key-size=512 --pbkdf2=argon2id -i 20000 --use-random /dev/sda1`

Comment: start from scratch imho and restore the data. since you already manipulate the partion,mostly a data restore company will tell you it's a bad thing